# a router which is connected through switch , two pc and one printer connected with lan all are pinging but printer not showing in pc 2

Tags: networking, printer

```
router 
 lan ip address 192.168.0.1
 subnet mask    255.255.255.0
 DNS Server     192.168.0.1
pc 1
 lan ip address 192.168.0.192
 subnet mask    255.255.255.0
 DNS Server     192.168.0.1
pc 2
 lan ip address 192.168.0.187
 subnet mask    255.255.255.0
 DNS Server     192.168.0.1
printer
 lan ip address 192.168.0.191
 subnet mask    255.255.255.0
 DNS Server     192.168.0.1
```

All are ping but in pc 2 printer did not show.

I have checked sharing setting, spoiler, and drivers.

Comment: Shut everything off.  Start the router, start the switch, start the computers, start the printer.  Can you see it?   Perhaps set the printer to a static IP address on your network so it does not get lost.

Comment: Can you manually add "printer" to "pc 2" by using the IP address of "printer"?

Comment: A drawing of your network would help.